# Macro to add all the elements of an array?

Tags: c

How do you define a macro to add all the elements of an array without using a loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int list[4] = {4, 8, 32, 42};
    int total;

    total = list[0] + list[1] + list[2] + list[3];

    printf("%d\n", total);
    return 0;
}
```

Can you define a macro that does something similar to this `total = list[0] + list[1] + list[2] + list[3];` ?

Comment: Not with the C preprocessor. It doesn't provide recursion or iteration mechanisms. m4 might be able to, though. Why not use a function for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only possible macro to add elements of array without using any loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define add(arr)\
    arr[1] + arr[2]+ arr[3] + arr[4];

int main(void)
{
    int list[4] = {4, 8, 32, 42};
    int total = add(list);
    printf("%d\n", total);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for